# Enable PHP modules for a specific user

Tags: php, ubuntu, fpm

On my Ubuntu 16.04 machine I installed the following PHP 7.4 modules:

```
[PHP Modules]
calendar
Core
ctype
date
dom
exif
FFI
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
sodium
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

but if I run:

```
php -m
```

under some specific user, I get:

```
[PHP Modules]
Core
date
filter
hash
libxml
openssl
pcntl
pcre
Reflection
session
sodium
SPL
standard
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

What does this mean?

How to make all PHP modules accessible for that user?

Tried to run

```
phpenmod gd
```

under this user, but got:

```
WARNING: Module gd ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.4/mods-available
WARNING: Module gd ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.4/mods-available
WARNING: Module gd ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.0/mods-available
WARNING: Module gd ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.0/mods-available
WARNING: Module gd ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.0/mods-available
```

and nothing changed.

When I call `phpinfo()` function under that user, it displays:

[image]

so I do not understand why `php -m` console command does not display `gd` module.

Comment: @AD7six yes, looks like GD module is enabled for HTTP, but not for CLI.

Comment: @AD7six but when I run `php -m` from my `admin` user, it prints all the modules.

Comment: `php -i` (or `php -i | grep ini`) will tell you what ini files they are loading. `which php` will _probably_ say each user is accessing a different executable, with different ini files. If that comment alone doesn't help you figure out what's happening - Please integrate your comments here to focus on 'the problem' (e.g. `running php as 'admin' I see x, running php as 'specific-other-user' I see y` ) - in particular the http phpinfo image is a misleading distraction.

Comment: whoops, missed this: `$ sudo su - username; php -m` <- this (or similar) makes it unambiguous who you are running commands as, it's helpful to show the command _and_ the output in the same code block, i.e. to show-not-describe things.

Comment: @AD7six yes, `admin` and other users display different `ini` files with `php -i | grep ini`

Comment: the error message you've now added to the question [has lots of existing references](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+Module+%22ini+file+doesn%27t+exist+under%22) - one of those is going to be a suitable duplicate :). It sounds like ultimately the problem is the ownership/permissions of those ini files.